# isAvailableForServiceType always returns true?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, slcomposeviewcontroller

Simple line of code:

```
NSLog(@"Checking on Facebook: %d -- Checking on Twitter: %d",[SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook], [SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]);
```

Problem is that I'm getting 1 for both BOOLs.  That's a problem because neither Twitter nor Facebook is setup with an account.  This is on the simulator, so wondering if people have experienced this is happening on devices as well?

Documentation says that it should only return true if the service is available and at least one account is setup.  But I'm getting true even without accounts setup.  I'd like to use the values to hide some social posting buttons so would like this to work.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? It's not working correctly on my iOS 6 devices either.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Did you run the that in Simulator?

It seems `isAvailableForServiceType` always returns `1` in Simulator.

Maybe you can test it in ipad with IOS6.

Comment: Yeah, simulator only (although I didn't have accounts set up on simulator).  I'll try on device itself, just disappointing to have another simulator/HW difference.

Comment: Any idea on how to get the expected behaviour on the simulator?

Answer (score 4):

From my experience, I can confirm this is a bug in iOS Simulator 6.0. The `isAvailableForServiceType` method always returns TRUE for any service type on iOS Simulator.

On actual device running current iOS 6.0 it is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

you can test `isAvailableForServiceType:` using iOS 7.1 on which it is working with simulator as well.

Here What I checked

```
NSLog(@"Facebook Enabled : %d",[SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
```

Please check this.

Answer (score 0):

I can also confirm that it's broken [i.e., returns True for all three services] in the Simulator (Xcode 4.5.1, iOS 6.0) -- but that it works properly running on a device (iPhone 4S, running iOS 6.0).

Answer (score 0):

`isAvailableForServiceType` returns `true` always in both iPhone and iPad simulators.

The same piece of code is working fine in the iOS 6 iPhone and iPad.