# iOS6 social framework bring up No Account Alert

Tags: ios

Similar to [iOS 6 Social framework not going to settings or no alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145322/ios-6-social-framework-not-going-to-settings-or-no-alert) but i am trying to use SLRequest:

I am trying to bring up the alert "No Facebook Account" when the user has not logged in to Facebook in the Settings. I have found that the alert appear AFTER you present the SLComposeViewController, rather than inside the if statement.

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])
{
    SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    //setup controller and callback code

    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

However, I am trying to use SLRequest and i dont want to present the SLComposeViewController, but instead, after checking the accounts, popup the alert. My code is here:

```
- (void)postImageFB
{
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
    NSLog(@"can post");
} else {
    NSLog(@"cant post");
}

ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
NSLog(@"accounts: %i", [accountsArray count]);

// Is it possible to popup the alert here if accounts = 0?

NSDictionary *options = @{ ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"123456789", ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"publish_stream"], ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceFriends };

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if(granted) {

        NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

        if ([accountsArray count] > 0) {

            ACAccount *facebookAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];

            NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"message": @"testing"};

            SLRequest *facebookRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                                            requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                                      URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos"]
                                                               parameters:parameters];

            [facebookRequest addMultipartData: [self getImageDataFromPlistWithFilename:@"image1.png"]
                                     withName:@"source"
                                         type:@"multipart/form-data"
                                     filename:@"TestImage"];

            facebookRequest.account = facebookAccount;

            [facebookRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
             {
                 if (error) {
                     NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
                 } else {
                     NSLog(@"responedata:%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
                 }

             }];
        }
    }
}];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have discovered that [isAvailableForServiceType always returns true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811906/isavailableforservicetype-always-returns-true)
so started testing on the device.

I figured that using an invisible SLComposeViewController to bring up the Alert seems to be a suitable workaround:

```
if (![SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

    SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    controller.view.hidden = YES;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil];

} else {

    // Put posting code here: SLComposeViewController or SLRequest

}
```

Comment: This however shows keyboard in the background which is not appropriate